# How to log myself out of ssh, from a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, logout

Connected to a remote server via SSH.

On occasion, I run a specific bash script.  When certain conditions are met (it's work completed successfully), I wish to be automatically logged out of the SSH tunnel.
In the normal login shell, I simply type `logout` to logout.

I am unable to do this from a bash script. If I put `logout` in a bash script, the error is:
 `` logout: not login shell: use `exit' ``

Query: How do you automatically log yourself out of an SSH connection from a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to logout after the successful completion of `/path/to/shell-script.sh`, use:

```
/path/to/shell-script.sh && logout
```

A ruder way to do it would be to have the script kill the parent:

```
kill -HUP "$PPID"
```

(PPID is a variable that is set by the [bash shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables), for one).

Comment: Thankyou, the second option is what I was seeking in this situation, require all the "logic" in a single file, in this specific cash. Merci!